# Remove iOS8 install file from iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, upgrade, ios

I have an iPad 3, running iOS7. Following some articles I read, alleging to degraded performance undr iOS8, I decided to not upgrade (if anyone can contribute any experience to the contrary - I'd be thanklful).

Recently, when I connected the iPad to my laptop to transfer some files, the iOS8 upgrade file was downloaded off the internet and onto my iPad. I now have a permanent notification asking me to upgrade, not to mention a 3.3GB file stuck on my iPad.

How do I get rid of it? Is there a way to delete it on the device, or do I need to do it through iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings → General → Usage and delete the iOS 8 update package from the list.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. And I also learned the file actually took 3.3GB!